# Equally spaced points on a sphere

Tags: geometric-topology, covering-spaces, symmetry, spherical-geometry, packing-problem

If you have an image on a plane,  you can represent it discreetly by sampling equally spaced points and putting the values in a matrix of some sort. (I'm not worried about the potential lost of information this may imply)

If you were to do the same for an image on a sphere, how could you pick the points to sample from. The Platonic Solids provide five examples of equally spaced points on a sphere. But are these the only five configurations possible? This would limit the maximum resolution of the image to 20 points of the vertices of the dodecaedro. (without resorting to imperfect configurations). This is a disappointingly low number of points. And my expectations say that this problem has less restrictions than the platonic solids do. So maybe it could have more solutions.

So, in one sentence, my question is:

**For an arbitrarily large N, can you always find a configuration of n > N points that are even spaced within the surface of a sphere?**

Maybe group-theory and the study of symmetries have something to say about this problem?

EDIT: After consulting some professors of mine, It turns out that this problem is closely related to the sphere packing problem.
One of my professors pointed to Sphere Codes:
http://neilsloane.com/packings/

The formal formulation of this problem is:  **Place n points on a sphere in d dimensions so as to maximize the minimal distance (or equivalently the minimal angle) between them.**

Comment: It is really not clear what you're asking (for me at least). Could you provide an example with a "one dimension function" - btw, what do you mean by that? That its image is a one dimensional vector space?

Comment: For example, I want a discrete image of the earth. If I were to take the integer combinations of latitudes and longitudes the points would not be evenly spaced.

Answer (score 1):

Since regular polygons include the equilateral triangle, square, and regular pentagon, which form the five Platonic solids, then since these solids can all be inscribed in a sphere, and Euclid shows that no other regular solids are possible (*Elements, XIII, 18)*, then wouldn't the twenty vertices of the regular dodecahedron be the maximum number of points that can be equally spaced on the surface of a sphere? Each of the twenty points is separated from its three nearest neighbors by an arc whose chord is the edge of the regular pentagon which makes up the inscribed solid. If this is a good argument, then there would be no solution for an arbitrary number of points.

Comment: This is a pretty good argument. But the argument that justifies there not being any more platonic solids takes into consideration the angle between adjacent faces. Since the faces are not of a concern here, I wonder if there are equally spaced points on a sphere which do not form the set of vertices for a platonic solids. Disregarding, of course two ore tree points, which are not enough to define a solid.

Comment: Yes, but if the points are equally spaced, wouldn't they have to be vertices of a Platonic solid inscribed in the sphere? Still, I'm thinking my answer needs revision. Suppose we put three more dodecahedra into the sphere, each with a vertex at the mid-point of one of the three arcs to the nearest vertices. This adds sixty points. Repeating this process would give ever more points, but always a multiple of 20. Similarly, if you start with a cube, you'll always have a multiple of 8 points. An odd number of points seems ruled out here,  and some even numbers too. I'm still thinking about this.

Comment: The points definitely define some solide. But there is no restriction that the faces be regular polygons (though maybe the equally spaced part implies that.) and there is also not the restriction that the solid be convex. So with some additional internal points a non convex solid could be defined for which there is not a limited number. Point being that this problem seems to have less restrictions than the platonic solids problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best method I can think of is unfortunately complex.  If you construct a standing spherical wave super imposed on the earth you can adjust the parameters of the wave to produce the desired number of nodes required.  I believe this will allow you to pick an arbitrary number of points and evenly distribute them.  A visual example of this can be seen on page 440 of this pdf http://www.mr-fusion.hellblazer.com/pdfs/spherical_nonlinear_waves.pdf
Perhaps someone here with a better grasp of differential equations and linear algebra can comment on plausibility of this approach.

Comment: Very unique approach! Its also interesting that it comes from differential equations rather than from abstract algebra. i'm not sure that it guaranties that the nodes be evenly spaced, though...

Comment: The link seems to be broken in 2022.

Comment: @Andyc: Based on other places on the web where this URL was posted in 2017, I think the link was to [a paper that can be found here](http://www.human-resonance.org/spherical_nonlinear_waves.pdf).  However it seems very distantly related to the Question above.

Comment: Wayback machine is always a good friend to have:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170809094915/http://www.mr-fusion.hellblazer.com/pdfs/spherical_nonlinear_waves.pdf

Nonlinear Standing and Rotating Waves on the Sphere
Christoph Gugg
Hansjoorg Kielhofer and Stanislaus Maier-Paape
Received December 14, 1998; revised October 20, 1999